# Set keyboard long press TimerTick

Tags: vb.net

Now when I want to press keyboard with one hit,  I want to write eeeeeeeeeeeee till keyup will stop write e. And &H69 = e

This my code mouse_event(&H69, 0, 0, 0, 0):

[image]

Comment: Using mouse_event() to generate a keyboard event makes excessively little sense.  Consider keybd_event() instead.  Both functions have been deprecated for a very long time, replaced by SendInput().

Comment: If GetAsyncKeyState(117) Then
            SetForegroundWindow(FindWindowByCaption(zero, programTitle))
            SendKeys.Send("e")
        End If
****** Now i need send "e" Always if i'm press F6 agian send e will stop
****** Let me how to